# Unity UI toolkit are there box-shadow?

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, game-development, ui-toolkit

I cannot find a good solution for CSS shadows (box-shadow) I am accustomed to. Unity provides USS that has many options to offer and so common to natural CSS though It lacks shadows (I guess). Can you explain what I can do to get shadows?